# Unable to change the default white splash screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

Here's the code in launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> 

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
 <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/applogo" />
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

I have changed the color to 'black'- yet I get a white splash screen, neither do the logo shows up.
I have placed the logo (png) in the drawable folder. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try building the project by clicking the Build icon.

Comment: are you using this launch_background.xml drawable in style.xml?

Answer (score 2):

first, you need 2 files to make this work, first are the files in the drawable and drawable-v21 folders they should have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_color" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/launch_icon" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

```
@color/background_color
```

is a custom color style for android which you would have to create it next

```
@mipmap/launch_icon
```

is a custom icon image you have in your mipmap folders you can create the sizes by using https://appicon.co

and the second file will create as a colors.xml in the values and values-night folder this file will carry the color you want to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want to remove the white screen at app boot time. Check This library, you can use color or logo image anything else instead of the white screen.**

[Click this Link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Here is the Preview

[image]

Comment: The link in this post just opens the video, it doesn't seem to be a link to a library

Comment: @Aamir I update my answer, you will get the library now  after clicking on the link

Answer (score 0):

**for android**
open launch_background.xml file inside the Res folder and add one new splash screen image in the drawable folder. Now change code in two places. [See tutorial example here](https://www.dripcoding.com/flutter-splash-screen/)

1. - Edit this launch_background.xml by adding a new item and set the splash screen image as an item value.

**For iOS app**
Open flutter project on Xcode for Adding splash screen to flutter ios app. To open the iOS module on Xcode, open android studio and on the top menu select tools. Go to flutter –> open ios module on Xcode.

On Xcode window, Click on **Runner-> Runner -> Assets.xcassets** folder. Here you can see LaunchImage paste your splash screen image with all three different dimensions in this folder.

[image]

**Open LaunchScreen.storyboard**
Again on the left side menu just below the Assets.xcassets folder, you will see LaunchScreen.Storyboard. Click on view controller scene -> view controller -> view.  Note: – select (click on ) view only don’t click on LaunchImage. You already paste the new splash screen in the LaunchImage folder in the previous step. So you will see the same new image here in this window. When you select (click on ) view then on the right side window you can see options to change view settings like content mode, background, alpha etc. change the background colour as you want and set content mode to scale to fill.

**Adjust Splash Screen**
You can adjust the splash screen position, size & background colour on the same window. Just click on launchImage OR select the image on the preview window. You can resize the image and can adjust the image position. On the Right side window, you can make another set as well.

**iOS App Splash Screen is Ready**.
Now flutter white splash screen problem has been resolved successfully for both android and iOS. You can change the flutter splash screen background color as per your requirements.